# DateCell(DateTimeFormat) constructor undeflined

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to add a date column to a cell table report using DateCell(format).

```
    DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat
        .getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_MEDIUM);

DateCell classDateCell = new DateCell(format);
```

I'm getting the error message: "The constructor DateCell(DateTimeFormat) is undefined", but the javadoc, http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?overview-summary.html, says that's a valid constructor.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you by any chance using the [com.google.gwt.i18n.*shared*.DateTimeFormat](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/shared/DateTimeFormat.html), the superclass of [com.google.gwt.i18n.*client*.DateTimeFormat](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)? The latter is the one the constructor you're interested in is looking for.

Comment: That did the trick. Could the make it more confusing? Eclipse was contributing to the problem as it was picking the wrong version for me. Guess I've learned not to completely trust eclipse. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this:

```
com.google.gwt.cell.client.DateCell

com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat
```

then you should be ok.